# filterAndTrim : Error in add(bin) : record does not start with '@'

Tags: r, gzip, bioinformatics, fastq, sequencing

I'm using dada 2 version ‘1.22.0’ on windows 10, i have list of compressed (.gz ) fastq files, when i use the function filterAndTrim i get this error message :

> Error in add(bin) : record does not start with '@'

But when i want to see if i can read th .gz file with library(ShortRead) :

```
library(ShortRead)
fn <- "path/to/example.fastq.gz"
reads <- readFastq(fn)
```

it doesn't give any error message message

I don't understand why the function filterAndTrim give the error message

> Error in add(bin) : record does not start with '@'

Do you have any solution?

Comment: If you view the [FASTQ format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) you nca see that identifiers need to start with "@". It sounds like your input file is not properly formatted. Can you unzip the first few lines to see what it looks like?

Comment: When i unzip the .gz files i can see that is start with @ ( i verified several .gz files), also i unziped all the files and i used the fastq files and it works, but i still don't undrestand why it doesn't work with the .gz files